# is there a list of avaiable domains

Tags: untagged

Is there a list or database of available domains (Web wide)?
Can I get a list of available domains from DNS servers (Public ones like 4.2.2.3)?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need a list of all domains? ALl i can read is spam.

Comment: @t1nt1n:For starting a crawl engine and make it's starting points as complete as possible.

Comment: Even Google doesn't do it this way.

Comment: There's a list of Top Level Domains (.com, .org. and so on).  There's a 255 character limit on domain names. 

for $i in $list_of_top_level_domains Do { 
for $n in 1 to 255 Do {
for $j in range(a..z) Do {
GET $j.$i
}}}

Or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

You can check domain if they are registered or not. Bud there is no list for all available domains because there are "infinite" combinations, aaaaaa.com, aaaaab.com, etc... you can use the whois utility to check for domain status or some online domain search tools.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a list or database of available domains (Web wide)?

No.

> Can I get a list of available domains from DNS servers (Public ones
>   like 4.2.2.3)?

Absolutely not - DNS resolvers only have information on **registered** domains.

There's nearly an infinite number of domains available - it would be impossible to list them all.

Comment: Well, DNS resolvers would also have information on requests that wound up as NXDOMAINs too. Some might store it for use, but certainly not in a public manner.

Comment: Registered domains are enough for me. is it possible to get a list of them?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check on an as-per basis, if you're looking to purchase a domain, random generators based on dictionary words might help you.

Try something like this: http://www.namestation.com/domain-search/variations

Comment: If you want a list of all domains currently in use... AFAIK that doesn't exist and I cant see how it'd be useful at all, aside from being spammy.